# Get size of folders on an FTP Server recursively

Tags: ftp, directory-listing

I have an FTP Server where a large number of files/folders are stored.

I would like to see how much is stored in each of the folders (including it's subfolders). Is there a way to do this? I.e. get a listing of all folders and theirs sizes on the FTP Server.

Ideally on Linux, Windows also possible.

Answer (score 1):

The `du` utility will do what you want.

Comment: I can only access the data via FTP on the Server, but "du only runs locally, so sorry, no, that does not do what I want in my case.

Comment: Then you'll need a script that can recursively walk the tree, starting up an FTP session, `cd`'ing into a directory, doing an `ls` or `dir`, parsing the results to find any subdirectories, then repeating.

Comment: hmm, sure I can do that, but that's what I was trying to avoid, I thought there must be some application or tool which can do that without implementing it myself...

Comment: I had a similar problem when I wanted to move one of my sites from a hosting service onto my own machine and I wanted to get the timestamps as well.  If you're stuck with the FTP interface, you're stuck with just the commands and the behaviors they give you.  You get a `dir` and an `ls` but they're both brain-dead and don't recurse.  I ended up writing a script (but it's nowhere near publishable quality.)

Comment: if you use du command with lftp it just does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to cPanel then you have very nice and prercise tool "Disk Space Usage" in "Files" category.